# Objects not serialising to XML (UTF-8) as expected .net?

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, encoding

I have a helper method that serialises an object, which works until you try to change the encoding... when received by the consumer web service, appears to be incorrect with some strange characters.

Here is the log entries from the app,

UTF-16 (this works):

```
2011-08-09 11:16:03,140 DEBUG SomeRestfulService *   xmlData    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<loginRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UserName>Admin</UserName>
  <Password>Password</Password>
  <MarketCode>GB</MarketCode>
</loginRequest>
```

UTF-8 (notice the strange character):

```
2011-08-09 11:21:30,687 DEBUG SomeRestfulService *   xmlData    ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><loginRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><UserName>Admin</UserName><Password>Password</Password><MarketCode>GB</MarketCode></loginRequest>
```

I don't know why it is has lost the layout.

Helper method:

```
Public Shared Function SerializeObject(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal encoding As Text.Encoding) As String

    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(obj.GetType)

    If encoding Is Nothing Then
        Using strWriter As New IO.StringWriter()
            serializer.Serialize(strWriter, obj)
            Return strWriter.ToString
        End Using
    Else
        Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream, xtWriter As New Xml.XmlTextWriter(stream, encoding)
            serializer.Serialize(xtWriter, obj)
            Return encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray())
        End Using
    End If


End Function
```

Note: If I pass encoding as nothing, the default encoding is UTF-16, everything is ok, originally I never had the encoding part, but it is a requirement, so needs to be in there.

Am I doing the serialising incorrectly when encoding to UTF-8? How can I fix this?

I tried the following to omit the BOM, but still have the same problem:

```
Dim utf8 As New Text.UTF8Encoding(True)
Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream, xtWriter As New Xml.XmlTextWriter(stream, utf8)
    serializer.Serialize(xtWriter, obj)
    Return utf8.GetString(stream.ToArray())
End Using
```

Comment: Your utf16 version is bad too.  You just can't see it since its BOM is invisible.

Comment: @Hans, the UTF-16 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) (BOM) that is often used at the start of text files or streams to indicate the byte order and the Unicode variant.

Your serializer is very strange. If you encode a string with some encoding such as UTF-8, you have to return it as an array of bytes. By first encoding the the XML in UTF-8 and then decoding the UTF-8 stream back to a string, you gain nothing (except introducing the problematic BOM).

Either go with UTF-16 only or return a byte array. As the function is now, the encoding just introduces problems.

**Update:**

Based on the code in the comment below, I'll see two approaches:

**Approach 1: Create a string with the serialized data and convert it to UTF-8 late**

```
Public Shared Function SerializeObject(ByVal obj As Object) As String

    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(obj.GetType)

    Using strWriter As New IO.StringWriter()
        serializer.Serialize(strWriter, obj)
        Return strWriter.ToString
    End Using

End Function

....

Dim serialisedObject As String = SerializeObject(object)
Dim postData As Byte() = New Text.UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(serialisedObject)
```

If you need a differnt encoding, change the last line. If you want to omit the byte order mark, pass `False` to `UTF8Encoding()`.

**Approach 2: Create the properly encoded data in the first place and continue with a byte array**

```
Public Shared Function SerializeObject(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal encoding As Text.Encoding) As Byte()

    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(obj.GetType)

    If encoding Is Nothing Then
       Set encoding = Encoding.Unicode
    End If

    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream, xtWriter As New Xml.XmlTextWriter(stream, encoding)
        serializer.Serialize(xtWriter, obj)
        Return stream.ToArray()
    End Using

End Function


....

Dim postData As Byte() = SerializeObject(object)
```

In this case, the `XmlTextWriter` directly encodes the data with the correct encoding. As since we have a byte array already, the last step is shorter: we directly have the data to send to the client.

Comment: I have to use UTF-8. Can you give example code? I got this code from here: http://ashish.tonse.com/2008/04/serializing-xml-in-net-utf-8-and-utf-16/

Comment: The method needs to return a string.

Comment: In order to help you use UTF-8, I'll need to see more code, namely how you pass the serialized data to the consumer web app. But the general approach will be to serialize the data with UTF-8 and then to go on with an array of bytes (and never convert it back to a string).

Comment: Strings have no encodings. Encodings are only relevant when converting a string to a byte array (or a binary stream).

Comment: I am passing it to a rest web service. When I set the post data I do the following: Dim postData As Byte() = New Text.UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(serialisedObject)

Comment: Thanks, this is the code fragment I was looking for. I've added more code samples to my answer. They might help you.

Comment: I can't tell you for sure (and I can't test it at the moment) whether `XmlTextWriter` will write `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="xyz"?>` or just `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. But if it works, it'll only work with approach 2. (Approach 1 initially uses a different encoding.)

Comment: Ah, that's embarrassing... I read Emit as Omit, this is where the problem is.